# TypeError: totalAmount.tofixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have written a code for firing an alert if a total due amount is greater than the input one.

For Example:

I am having four input boxes where I'm taking some input in terms of amount by user. If he made a purchase of 500 bucks and trying to input in first box as 450 and in second one 200 so an alert box must be triggered as amount is greater than the total due.

It works fine in Chrome but giving error in Chrome as

**TypeError: totalAmount.tofixed is not a function**
I have shown my script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckPayment(obj)
    {
        debugger;
        var creditCardAmount = 0;
        var aCHAmount = 0;
        var cashAmount = 0;
        var checkAmount = 0;
        var deviceFinancing = 0;
        var totalAmount = 0;
        var totalDue = 0;
     
        
        var txtCreditCardAmount = document.getElementById('<%=txtCreditCardAmount.ClientID %>');
        var txtACHAmount = document.getElementById('<%=txtACHAmount.ClientID %>');
        var txtCashAmount = document.getElementById('<%=txtCashAmount.ClientID %>');
        var txtCheckAmount = document.getElementById('<%=txtCheckAmount.ClientID %>');
        var txtDeviceFinancing = document.getElementById('<%=txtDeviceFinancing.ClientID %>');
        var total = document.getElementById('<%=lblTotal.ClientID %>');
        var upfrontTotal = document.getElementById('<%=lblUpfrontTotal.ClientID %>');
        
        if(txtCreditCardAmount != null && txtCreditCardAmount.value != "")
        {
            creditCardAmount = parseFloat(txtCreditCardAmount.value);
        }
        if(txtACHAmount != null && txtACHAmount.value != "")
        {
            aCHAmount = parseFloat(txtACHAmount.value);
        }
        if(txtCashAmount != null && txtCashAmount.value != "")
        {    
            cashAmount = parseFloat(txtCashAmount.value);
        }
        if(txtCheckAmount != null && txtCheckAmount.value != "")
        {
            checkAmount = parseFloat(txtCheckAmount.value);
        }
        if(txtCheckAmount != null && txtCheckAmount.value != "")
        {
            deviceFinancing = parseFloat(txtDeviceFinancing.value);
        }        
        if(upfrontTotal != null && upfrontTotal.textContent  != "")
        {
            upfrontTotal = upfrontTotal.textContent ;
        }
        if(total != null && total.innerText != "")
        {
            total = total.innerText;
        }
        if(upfrontTotal != null && upfrontTotal.innerText != "")
        {
            totalDue = parseFloat(upfrontTotal.substring(1));
        }
        if(total != null && total.innerText != "")
        {
            totalDue = parseFloat(total.substring(1));
        }
        
        totalAmount = parseFloat(creditCardAmount + aCHAmount + cashAmount + checkAmount + deviceFinancing);
        debugger;
         if(totalDue < parseFloat(totalAmount.tofixed(2)))
         {            
             if(obj != null)
             {
                 var itm = document.getelementbyid(obj.id);
                 var val = itm.innertext;
                 val = itm.innerhtml;
                 obj.value = "";
                 settimeout(function(){obj.focus();}, 1);
             }
             alert('entered amount is more than due amount')
             return false;
         }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not `tofixed`. It should be:

```
totalAmount.toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing your if statement to:

`if(totalDue < parseFloat(totalAmount.toFixed(2)))`

you just forgot an upper case F in method name

Comment: How is this answer different from mine?

Comment: It's not.
I haven't refreshed the page.